# Java Point2D and Comparable

Tags: java, comparable, treeset

I'm making a TreeSet of Point2D.Float type, creating it with a custom Comparable class that implements compare() of Point2D type. However, on calling "contains" on the TreeSet, I get a classcast error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.geom.Point2D$Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

The set is created as so:

```
private CoordinateComparator coordCompare;
public TreeSet<Point2D.Float> coordSet = new TreeSet<Point2D.Float>(coordCompare);
```

Here is my compare class:

```
 public class CoordinateComparator implements Comparator<Point2D.Float> {
 public CoordinateComparator() {}

 @Override
 public int compare(Point2D.Float p1, Point2D.Float p2) {
        if (p1.getX() < p2.getX()) 
         return -1;
        if (p1.getX() > p2.getX())
         return 1;
        if (p1.getY() < p2.getY())
         return -1;
        if (p1.getY() > p2.getY())
         return 1;
        return 0;
 }
}
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong? I've been stuck here for hours trying to debug it to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: You are initializing your CoordinateComparator before you pass it to your TreeSet right? Like this: coordCompare = new CoordinateComparator();

Comment: @John: Post this as an answer; Dan can then accept it.

Comment: The above code should throw an NPE, but it seems it doesn't.  Hmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding my previous comment as answer. You need to initialize your Comparator first.

```
 public class CoordinateComparator implements Comparator<Point2D.Float> {
 public CoordinateComparator() {}

 @Override
 public int compare(Point2D.Float p1, Point2D.Float p2) {
        if (p1.getX() < p2.getX()) 
         return -1;
        if (p1.getX() > p2.getX())
         return 1;
        if (p1.getY() < p2.getY())
         return -1;
        if (p1.getY() > p2.getY())
         return 1;
        return 0;
 }
}

CoordinateComparator coordCompare = new CoordinateComparator();
TreeSet<Point2D.Float> coordSet = new TreeSet<Point2D.Float>(coordCompare);
```

@the-alchemist, I'm guessing he's getting the Class Cast Exception and not a NPE because it's trying to cast to do `(Comparator) null` and for some reason that's failing before it actually tries to call the compare method. Without the stack trace I'm not sure though.