# How to Convert Point2D.Double's to use aritmetic operator >

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have this code:

```
private Point2D.Double getMedianX(Point2D.Double[] arr, int left, int right) {
    //Write codes here
    int center = (left + right) / 2;
    // order left & center
    if (arr[left] > arr[center])
        swap(arr ,left, center);
```

What I wanted to do is use the > arithmetic operation in Point2D.Double object. But as the following error says I cannot use arithmetic operators in Point2D.Double elements.

```
Operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double', 'java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double'
```

How can I modify my code to work with > operator and other aritmetic operators without changing the input elements of the function `getMedianX`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3692087/438992 Java doesn't do operator overloading (for better or worse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you *exactly* what is wrong. You can't use arithmetic operators on Point2D.Double objects, and this makes sense since a `Point2D` represents both an X and a Y value in 2D space -- which one are you comparing?

You will need to extract the double values that the Point2D object holds, which as per the API will require your calling either `.getX()` or `.getY()` (or both), and then use these in your arithmetic comparisons.

Comment: Many things make sense now. Thank you for your help.